# Merge the "vocabulary-building" tag with the "vocabulary" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tagging

There are three questions tagged with [vocabulary-building](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary-building). The tag should be deleted, and the questions tagged with [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary).

Comment: So far as I can tell, this has been done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I know what either of those mean.

Likewise for [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) .

There are hardly any "vocabulary-building" ones, so I'd just delete those (or reduce to [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary).

We probably don't need both [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) and [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary), 
and possibly neither.